# How to draw this in Latex using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

How to draw this using Tikz????

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? This is simple circle tith tick. See some examples in http://www.texample.net/

Comment: Draw a circle, then draw a bunch of dots (filled circles) along the border, then place nodes with labels near the dots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw circle[radius=4cm];
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {20,1,21,0,8,15,6,16,5,17,4,18,3,19,2}
{\path (0,0) -- (\Y*24:4) node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.8pt]{} 
node[pos=1.1] {$\X$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou so much for your kind help.

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution only for either fun or comparison purpose.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\degrees[15]
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=16]{0}{15 AnytoRad}{2*cos(t)|2*sin(t)}{A}
    \pscircle{2}
    \foreach \a [count=\i from 0] in {20,1,21,0,8,15,6,16,5,17,4,18,3,19,2}
    {
        \qdisk(A\i){2pt}
        \uput{2mm}[!dt RadtoAny \i\space mul](A\i){$\a$}
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the help

Comment: _RadtoAny_ Where is "it" ?

Comment: `RadtoAny` will be useful if `\degrees[x]` is in used. It converts radian to `x`, for example, if you call `\degrees[10]` then an expression `2 Pi mul RadtoAny` equals to `10`, `y RadtoAny` equals to `10*y/(2Pi)`.

Answer (score 2):

a bit shorter PSTricks version. Run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
\degrees[15]
\pscircle{2}
\foreach \a [count=\i from 0] in {20,1,21,0,8,15,6,16,5,17,4,18,3,19,2}
    {%
        \qdisk(2;\i){2pt}\uput{2mm}[\i](2;\i){\a}
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It can be made shorter by removing `\usepackage{pst-plot}`.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the help