# How to draw following figure in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

How to draw this using tikz??????

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/494663/how-to-draw-this-in-latex-using-tikz The TikZ manual is great. Read it. People here are happy to draw stuff, but you should put in some effort yourself.

Comment: Ha i'm new to this stack exchange, i didn't know all these stuff available, now i have found it, thankyou.

Comment: From the answers provided to your first question, which is almost the same as this one, you should already be able to draw a circle and put some nodes on the surface of that circle. That would be a good starting point and show other users that you are at least trying it on your own. Also, the other question linked to a list of learning material, including the TikZ manual. Please put at least a bit of effort into your questions, simple do-it-for-me questions are discouraged on that site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll see it is much more fun if you try out yourself. The purpose of this site is to help you when you are stuck. I didn't downvote your question but most likely the downvote is related to the lack of own attempts.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.8pt]{} circle[radius=4cm];
\foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {15,4,16,13,6,14,5}
{
\draw \ifnum\Y<5(0,0) -- (\Y*45:4)\else
(0,0) -- ({180+(\Y-4)*60}:4) \fi
 node[fill,circle,inner sep=1.8pt]{} node[pos=1.1] {$\X$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I completely agree with your statement, however if i know something then only i can try something else, to understand those basic things only i'm asking questions. Once i understand basic things i can further improve myself with the help of your answers.

Comment: @TouqeerAhmed Yes, sure, the beginning is hard.